# Get the decimal part of a number

Tags: sql, format, substr, dolphindb

I want to extract the decimal part of a number and use it as a column name. For example, extract “001“ from 0.001. Can I use `decimalFormat` for this?

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS.

Comment: Do you want to do this in SQL or programming language - which one? Maybe: `x - Int(x)`. If you want to pad with leading zeros, the result will be a string, not a number: `Format(x - Int(x), "000")`. Or convert to a string and use other string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the script below using DolphinDB:

```
x=1.001
decimalFormat(x - floor(x), "0.000").substr(2)
```

The result is 001.